# Problemas de seleccion LI javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

tengo el siguiente problema.. estoy creando una todo app.. la cual tiene 3 elementos que ya venian en el html (los cuales no se pueden cambiar) y los demas mediantes las funciones(que ya se hicieron) se creen con determinado evento.

el problema es que los 3 elementos que vienen definidos en la plantilla html no los puedo eliminar, accese a ellos mediante querySelector('li') pero solo toma 1 li de los 3. adjunto el codigo HTML

```
    <div id="container">
    <h1 class="todo-header">To do List</h1>
    <input id="addToDo" type="text" placeholder="Add to do here">
    <ul>
      **<li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat</li> //solo accedo a este**
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Drink</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Sleep</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

adjunto el codigo para jsvascript que me hace tomar solo un elemento.

```
let li = document.querySelector('li');
li.style.color = 'red';
```

solo toma el primer LI. he intentado hasta recorrerlos.

Comment: `document.querySelector` se queda con el primer elemento que cumple los requisitos, si quieres una colección de elementos usa document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 4):

Necesitas hacerlo con `querySelectorAll()` asi:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1 class="todo-header">To do List</h1>
    <input id="addToDo" type="text" placeholder="Add to do here">
    <ul>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Eat</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Drink</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Sleep</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Vale amigo! efectivamente en una mala pasada no llame la posicion de los elementos!! :D gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Usa `document.querySelectorAll('li');`

Sería algo así:

```
let liList = document.querySelectorAll('li');

liList.forEach(li => {
    li.style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: agradecido! no habia puedo la posicion en el loop!:D

Comment: @ricardoleivasikic el problema es que estabas usando `querySelector`, que solo selecciona uno (el primero), deberías usar `querySelectorAll` que selecciona todos (como el nombre indica). No es que no estuviera la posición del loop, es que solo seleccionabas un elemento. Un placer poder ayudar.

Comment: correcto, es que estaba probando que me tomara todos los elementos li del dom y me los recorriera..ya que necesito disparar un evento click que elimine cada uno. en eso ando ahora jaja